# Why isn't my table showing when doing a create table statement using airflow?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, airflow

So, I am trying to create a table in my Redshift DB by using airflow. My connection works and I tested it with a SQL command but when I change the sql command to a create table command it runs successfully but it doesn't show up in my redshift DB.

Here is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.hooks.postgres_hook import PostgresHook
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'james_c',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019,4,1),
    'email': ['myemail@aol.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}


def get_activated_sources():
    request ="CREATE TABLE if not exists schema1.db1.tb1 (vendor_id varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY, vendor_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);"
    pg_hook = PostgresHook(postgre_conn_id="postgres_default", schema='schema1')
    connection = pg_hook.get_conn()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(request)
        #cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()


with DAG('create_sample_table_dagg', description='testing my redshift connection', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='@once', catchup=False) as dag:


    hook_task = PythonOperator(task_id='hook_task', python_callable=get_activated_sources)
```

Any ideas/suggestion as to why its running and completing by not actually creating the table in redshift?f

Comment: Possible duplicate question of this?  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94096/redshift-table-not-showing-up-in-tables-for-schema

Comment: Have you tried adding a SQLSensor downstream of hook_task to check if the table exists ? In your code right now there is nothing checking for the table existence. Also, the create statement can be ran directly with a PostgresOperator instead of PythonOperator

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine, you just need to write:

`connection.commit()`

under

`cursor.execute(request)`